# gradle wrapper creates wrong distributionurl

Tags: gradle, wrapper

When i write command "gradle wrapper" from commandline/gitbash, build returns successful and gradle creates the gradle-wrapper.properties. However, when I open the properties file with notepad, i see that distributionUrl has Turkish character in it. I mean like this : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-b\u0131n.zip
(which is equal to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bın.zip). Because of that "ı" character gradlew command fails. How do i make this distributionurl right ? (not with "ı" but "i")

Comment: By the way, I tried these :
1- add distributionurl to build.gradle's task wrapper method, it works. However, I want to solve this Turkish Character issue not finding alternative solutions.
2- After gradle wrapper command done successfully, I changed the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file manually. (changed "ı" with "i")

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the gradle wrapper command. You should report it. The easiest workaround is to fix the URL manually.

Comment: @Henry Yea, i guess this is a bug. I removed the system environment path for version 3.1 and download version 2.2 and add it to the path. It works perfectly.